# Django Include() in urls.py with two apps

Tags: python, django, path, include

I believe this is a simple question but I am having a hard time figuring out why this is not working.

I have a django project and I've added a second app (sales).  Prior to the second app, my urls.py simply routed everything to the first app (chart) with the following:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('chart.urls')),
]
```

and it worked fine.

I have read the docs over and over a looked at many tutorials, so my impression is that I can simply amend the urls.py to include:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('sales/', include('sales.urls')),
    path('', include('chart.urls')),
]
```

and it should first look for a url with sales/ and if it finds that then it should route it to sales.urls, and if it doesn't find that then move on and route it to chart.urls.  However, when I load this and type in 127.0.0.1:8000/sales, it returns the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/sales/
Raised by:  chart.views.index
```

which tells me that it is not routing my sales/ url to sales.urls but to chart.urls.  When I change `path('', include('chart.urls'))`, to `path('', include('sales.urls'))`, it does route it to sales.urls so I know that my sales.urls file is set up correctly.

I know this is probably an easy question but I cannot figure it out with anything I've read.  Any help is appreciated.

chart.urls:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.chart, name='dashboard'),
    path('', views.index, name='index', kwargs={'pagename': ''}),
    path('<str:pagename>/', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

sales.urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('sales/', views.sales, name='Sales Dashboard'),
]
```

Comment: Have you added the apps in "INSTALLED_APPS " in settings.py?

Comment: So there is an ambiguity between URLs? Two views can have the *same* URL? Don't do that! It will break `reverse(..)` functions. Actually it is better that regardless of the order of the URLs, every URL has exactly one view and vice versa (relative to view parameters of course).

Comment: What is in sales.urls and chart.urls? Exactly what pattern are you expecting to serve the /sales/ request?

Comment: @Chris I couldn't reproduce the behavior. Can you add the contents of `sales.urls` and `chart.urls`

Comment: I've added the chart.urls and sales.urls.  Individually those both work when the myapp.urls actually routes to them, but I clearly and missing something.  I appreciate all the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct url for the sales page in your case would be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sales/sales/`.

This is because `sales/` is then looking in the included `sales.urls` and not finding any urls at the root `/` (the only url included there is at `sales/` (within `sales/`) so will be `sales/sales/`

*Reply to an OLD question but may be useful for others...*

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.urls import path, include
```

dont for get to import include

Answer (score -2):

Do this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('chart.urls')),
    url(r'^sales/', include('sales.urls')),
]
```

you are not doing it properly since you are not telling your app where go once it is loaded .this `r'^'` to go directly to chart.url `url(r'^', include('chart.urls')),`

Comment: `''` and `'^'` are exactly equivalent.