# Including a certain url in urls.py makes the wrong view function execute

Tags: python, django

My main application is called `lpbsmain`, and I have another app called `dashboard`.

`lpbsmain/urls.py` includes `path('main/', include('dashboard.urls'))` in the `urlpatterns` variable.

`dashboard/urls.py`  looks like...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('<str:useremail>/', views.dashboard, name='main'),
    path('base_dash/', views.base_dashboard, name='baseDash')
]
```

`dashboard/views.py` has two view functions, `dashboard()` and `base_dashboard()`

```
import requests, json
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def base_dashboard(request):
    print("base dashboard view func print statement")
    return render(request, "base-main-dashboard.html")

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def dashboard(request, useremail):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # removed code in this conditional because it's not relevant
        return render(request, "index.html", {'Past30Dates':json.dumps(past_30_dates), 'Past30Values':json.dumps(past_30_values), 'Past60Dates':json.dumps(past_60_dates), 'Past60Values':json.dumps(past_60_values), 'fullEmail':useremail, 'shortenedEmail':shortenedEmail})
    else:
        redirect("login")
```

**The problem:** So if you try to go to the url `/main/base_dash`, my intent is to see `base-main-dashboard.html`. Instead, I actually see `index.html`. From adding print statements, I see that whenever I go to the url `/main/base_dash/`, the view function `dashboard(useremail)` is actually being executed, not `base_dashboard()`. Normally, `dashboard(useremail)` gets executed from the url `main/<useremail>` as expected. But now it's also executing at that url and `main/base_dash`.

The only way this stops is if I remove  `path('<str:useremail>/', views.dashboard, name='main'),` from `dashboard/urls.py`. Then, if I go to `main/base_dash` then only `base_dashboard()` gets executed.

1. If these view functions are mapped to two different urls, I don't get why going to one url is triggering the other. So are they mapped correctly or did I do something wrong?
2. Why would the existence of one url affect the other in this case?

I'm running django locally on a development server.

Answer (score 0):

The order of urls, when django scans the url patterns it gives more importance to the 1st one

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request

-> In this case any url ( /main/base_dash ) will be matched against < str:useremail > and it checks out ( base_dash can be parsed as string )

Either refactor the url pattern ( which i recommend to be more good approach )

```
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('base_dash/', views.base_dashboard, name='baseDash'),
    path('email/<str:useremail>/', views.dashboard, name='main'),
]
```

or just try changing the order as follows.

```
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('base_dash/', views.base_dashboard, name='baseDash'),
    path('<str:useremail>/', views.dashboard, name='main'),
]
```

Comment: Changing the order fixed it. I guess I didn't interpret the docs properly - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request "Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL, matching against path_info."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you make a call to the link via the include and then add the extension again, and this does not work

try this

```
path('', include('dashboard.urls'))
```

res:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724903/django-include-in-urls-py-with-two-apps)